# Странности поведения FOR ORDINALITY для json_table с nested path в oracle 12.1

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

Имею json вида:

```
[
  {
     "debitOverturn": "939.34",
     "table": [
       {
         "debit": "",
         "credit": "939.34"
       },
       {
         "debit": "939.34",
         "credit": ""
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "debitOverturn": "939.34",
     "table": [
       {
         "debit": "",
         "credit": "939.34"
       },
       {
         "debit": "939.34",
         "credit": ""
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

Делаю к нему запрос (на oracle 12.1):

```
SELECT jt.u_lvl,
       jt.debitOverturn,
       jt.l_lvl,
       jt.debit,
       jt.credit
 FROM some_table s,
     JSON_TABLE (s.clob_for_json,'$[*]' COLUMNS (
        u_lvl FOR ORDINALITY,
        debitOverturn VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.debitOverturn',
        NESTED PATH '$.table[*]'
            COLUMNS (
                l_lvl FOR ORDINALITY,
                debit VARCHAR2(38) PATH '$.debit',
                credit VARCHAR2(38) PATH '$.credit'))) AS jt
   WHERE s.hash = :l_hash
```

и получаю довольно странный результат для счетчика:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
2   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
3   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
4   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

т.е. U_LVL считает строки не своего уровня, а вообще все.

Повторяю запрос на домашней виртуалке с 12.2 - результат ожидаемый:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
2   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
2   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

Самое смешное, что при повторе запроса на оракловском livesql.oracle.com, результат еще страньше:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

Это как вообще понимать? Баг? Поведение ORDINALITY настраивается где-то?

Comment: На 12.1.0.2.0 выполняется как (1). А у вас на какой первый результат?

Comment: забыл явно указать, первый результат - 12.1, второй -12.2, третий - оракловский livesql (не глядел как он себя идентифицирует)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге оказался [баг](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2301973.1) в json_table, если кому интересно, для исправления нужно установить [патч](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=patch&id=20885778) на 12.1.0.2.0, на 12.2 уже исправлено.